# Limit of pseudo-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to prove that $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k\frac{n}{n+k}} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}2^{-k} = 2$$ yet I'm a little stuck. I can quite easily prove that $$\displaystyle u_n := \sum_{k=0}^{2n}2^{-k\frac{n}{n+k}}$$ is bounded, but I struggle to do more. Have you got an idea of the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is straightforward to see that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)=2$$

---

Next, we write for a fixed number $0<K<2n$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}} &=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^K\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}+\sum_{k=K+1}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Given a number $\epsilon>0$, we choose $K$ large enough so that both

$$\left(\frac12\right)^K<\epsilon/2$$

and

$$\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^{K/3}}{2^{1/3}-1}<\epsilon/2$$

---

Clearly, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^K\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}=2-\left(\frac12\right)^K\tag2$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=K+1}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}\le \sum_{K+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{1/3}=\frac{\left(\frac12\right)^{K/3}}{2^{1/3}-1}\tag3$$

---

Putting it all together shows that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{\frac{1}{1+k/n}}=2$$

Comment: That's the way I tried unsuccessfully, thank you!

Comment: @Maxence1402 and this is why you shouldn't accept an answer too quickly.

Comment: @maxence1402 You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n} 2^{-k\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n(k)
$$
with $f_n$ defined for $x\geq 0$ as
$$
f_n(x) = 2^{-x\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{n}}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,2n]}(k)\,.
$$

Note that (i) $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = 2^{-x}$, and that (ii) for all $x$ and $n$, we have
$$
0\leq f_n(x) \leq \frac{1}{2^{x/3}}  \stackrel{\rm def}{=} g(x)
$$
which is summable. Thus, by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem),
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_n(k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = \boxed{2}
$$
as claimed.

*Note that the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), instead of the DCT, would work as well here.*

Comment: Okay, but the DCT is about integrals, not series. So, without any measure theory or knowledge on distributions, how does it work?

Comment: @Maxence1402 A series is an integral with the counting measure -- all such theorems carry over to series as well.

Comment: @Maxence1402 See e.g. [these lecture notes](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~krieger/analysisresults.pdf) for a self-contained proof.

Comment: +1 for the more mature approach

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks :) But my comment (under your answer) was more to point out to Maxence1402 that accepting, then unaccepting an answer one day after is not best practice -- if an answer is not entirely satisfying, one should mention it and wait a couple more days to see if any other pops up (as yours did :))

Comment: I agree.  I've seen reversals of accepted answers flip, and the flip again.